# Update jquery variable from ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can i update a variable that exist outside of ajax call from an event that exist inside this ajax call? Thia is just a piece of my full code,  by default i´m setting the var units with the value metric, but when my selectbox changes (inside ajax call) i want to update the var units with the new selected value!!

How can i do this?

Many thanks in advance

```
// Define Latitude & longitude
var lat = 37.0971034;
var lon = -8.471261;

// Temperature Metric - metric (Celsius) or imperial(fahrenheit)
var units = 'metric';

// Number of Forecast Days
var n_days = '5';

// Define Urls
var forecast = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat="+ lat +"&lon="+ lon +"&units=" + units +"&cnt=5";


// Define Today´s Date
//var date = new Date();
//var currentdate = (date.getDay()+1) + '.' + date.getMonth() + '.' + date.getFullYear();   


// append event onchange
$("select[name=units]").on("change", function(){
    units = $(this).val();    
    updateForecast();
});

function updateForecast() {
   var forecast = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat="+ lat +"&lon="+ lon +"&units=" + units +"&cnt=5";
    // Define Ajax Call
    $.ajax({
       url: forecast,
       async: false,
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {
            // show new forecast (data)
            // alert(data);
            // New part from your code 
            // access the first item
            var firstItem = data.list[0]; 

            var html =  '<div>' + data.city.name + '</div>';
            html += '<div> Max '+ firstItem.temp.max + '</div>';
            html += '<div> Min '+ firstItem.temp.min +'</div>';

            $('#weather_output').empty().append(html);

            for(var i = 1, l = data.list.length; i < l; i++) {

                html = '<div>Temp Max'+ data.list[i].temp.max + '</div>';
                html += '<div>Temp Min'+ data.list[i].temp.min + '</div>';


                $('#weather1_output').empty().append(html);

            }
       },
       error: function( data ) {
         alert( "ERROR:");
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: _“but when my selectbox changes (inside ajax call)”_ – that doesn’t make sense to me; your select field does not change “inside” the ajax call. With your code, you would just be binding the event handler to the select field over and over again, each time your AJAX call was completed successfully.

Comment: Can you tell what `data` is returning ajax call? I must agree with @CBroe this make no sense

Comment: I´m don´t have much experience with ajax... how can i solve this? Thanks a lot to try to help me :)

Comment: Please have a look on my code!!! What i want is update temperature from C to F, on select change!!! :)

Comment: Take a look to my answer @Legues it should solve your problem. :)

Comment: Ok I misunderstood your question... updating my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. This make no sense inside ajax call, insted do this:

```
// Define Latitude & longitude
var lat = 37.0971034;
var lon = -8.471261;

// Temperature Metric - metric (Celsius) or imperial(fahrenheit)
var units = 'metric';

// Number of Forecast Days
var n_days = '5';

// Define Urls


// Define TodayÂ´s Date
//var date = new Date();
//var currentdate = (date.getDay()+1) + '.' + date.getMonth() + '.' + date.getFullYear();   


// append event onchange
$("select[name=units]").on("change", function(){
    units = $(this).val();    
    updateForecast();
});

function updateForecast() {

    var forecast = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat="+ lat +"&lon="+ lon +"&units=" + units +"&cnt=5";

    // Define Ajax Call
    $.ajax({
       url: forecast,
       async: false,
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {

            var firstItem = data.list[0]; 
            var secondItem = data.list[0].weather[0]; 

            var html =  '<div class="'+ secondItem.icon +'">' + data.city.name + '</div>';
            html += '<div> Max '+ firstItem.temp.max + '</div>';
            html += '<div> Min '+ firstItem.temp.min +'</div>';

            $('#weather_output').empty().append(html); // ADDED .empty()
            $('#weather1_output').empty();

            // skip first i = 1
            for(var i = 1; i < data.list.length; i++) {

                var html2 = '<div>Temp Max'+ data.list[i].temp.max + '</div>';
                html2 += '<div>Temp Min'+ data.list[i].temp.min + '</div>';

                $('#weather1_output').append(html2);
            }
       },
       error: function( data ) {
         alert( "ERROR:");
       }
    });
}

updateForecast(); // for init update!
```

What this example does? It's getting new forecast on every unit change.

if you are using `units` only in ajax call you can do something like this :

```
//on event change
updateForecast(unit);
...
function updateForecast(unit) {
// and than pass that unit
```

There is many place to optimize this my example ;)

Comment: Your code in fact update the value, but adds all the outputted date every time i change the select box!! LOL Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Try now :) `$('#weather_output').empty()...` i have added this part to empty html before append.

Comment: Ok... we are nearly there. Now it´s not showing any data on document ready... just when i update the select box. Then the for function inside ajax success it´s only outputting one result from 4 results. why?:)

Comment: I have update the answer try now @Legues . There was bug at for loop, html value was override.

Comment: For initial update add `updateForecast();` at the end of script. @Legues

Comment: @Legues you didnt see my example right. Remove empty from second append (in for loop)! :)

Comment: It´s almost perfect... but from the for function, i still getting just one value from 4!! :)

Comment: $('#weather1_output').empty() need's only one time in your code. Remove empty() from loop. Look my example for part. @Legues (this line : `$('#weather1_output').append(html2);` )

Comment: No update, you told "...i still getting just one value from 4" and after that "Now it´s looping and adding 4 results every time i update the select box" . That means that is working just fine. You have your 4 values :)

Comment: No, sorry... have a look here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23044665/weather/index.html

Comment: @Legues I have update my example, copy whole code to yours js.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set your change listener inside your onSuccess event of your Ajax call. If what you want to do is to use some data returned from the Ajax call when the onChange event happens then you should store that data at the same scope where your units variable is and then use it there... I hope that makes sense.

Here is an example:

```
var units = null;

function updateTemperature(){
    //At this point the units variable should have the selected value from the dropdown

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat="+ lat +"&lon="+ lon +"&units=" + units +"&cnt=5";,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            //do whatever you wanna do on successful Ajax call
        }
    });
}

$("select[name=units]").on("change", function(){
    //Storing the selected units from the dropdown, so that we can use them in the Ajax call
    units = this.value;
    updateTemperature();
});
```

Comment: It makes sense... but how can i do it? :)

Comment: If i may..this code block isn't that good for one reason.. When you use ajax call the scope is being changes to the request scope. Storing a temp variable from one scope and use it in the other is just wrong. For that you need to use set/get method and thats it.. Please build a proper Set funcation and use it inside the 'success' callback...Also...if the request fails, it can cause bugs and different handling

Answer (score 0):

You should move

$("select[name=units]").on("change", function(){

outside ajax success

Change will happen when user interacts with the dropdown and you should attach event only one time (outside ajax success). It is not executed within the ajax success, it is only attached.
Not sure what is dependency between success and change event. Is there a reason to do it that way?

Comment: Yes. The thing is i´m passing units variable outside ajax call because i want to load unit metric parameter by default. Then if the user wants to update to imperial (F) this should update my output. Success loads my variables to forecast one. The change event will only update the units one!

Comment: :) Seems I've seen the question before the update.
Anyway, you have accepted the best answer so no point to continue.